# Hibernate IDENTITY vs SEQUENCE entity identifier generators

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

This [article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2011/sequence-sql-server-2011/) says:

> Unlike identity, the next number for the column value will be retrieved from memory rather than **from the disk** – this makes Sequence significantly faster than Identity

Does it mean that ID comes from disk in case of identity? If yes, then which disk and **how**?

Using sequence, I can see in the log, an extra select query to DB while inserting a new record. But I didn't find that extra select query in the log in case of identity.
Then **how sequence becomes faster than identity**?

Answer (score 50):

**Strategy used by sequence:**

Before inserting a new row, ask the database for the next sequence value, then insert this row with the returned sequence value as ID.

**Strategy used by identity:**

Insert a row without specifying a value for the ID. After inserting the row, ask the database for the last generated ID.

The number of queries is thus the same in both cases. **But**, Hibernate uses by default a strategy that is more efficient for the sequence generator. In fact, when it asks for the next sequence value, it keeps th 50 (that's the dafault, IIRC, and it's configurable) next values in memory, and uses these 50 next values for the next 50 inserts. Only after 50 inserts, it goes to the database to get the 50 next values. This tremendously reduces the number of needed SQL queries needed for automatic ID generation.

The identity strategy doesn't allow for such an optimization.

Comment: I would also add that SQL Server "reserves" a batch of sequence numbers in its cache (thus **memory**). By default it's 50 (that's probably also the reson why NH developers picked this value for their purpose). When those 50 numbers got used, SQL Server needs to update its system tables that store last used number in a given sequence, in order to "reserve" next batch of numbers - this is a **disk** operation. Identities are also cached but the cache size is 5x smalled (counts 10 numbers) and thus the "sequence generator" touches disk more frequently.

Comment: @JB, thanks .I think this is what i was looking for.But what is the meaning of - "ask the database for the last generated id" in case of Identity, is it like auto-increment.Can i say there is a data transfer also in the reverse direction, from db to application(round trip), in case of Identity and it is only from application to db(one way) in case of Sequence(assuming we don't have allocationSize defined for sequence).Probably i am confused, please rectify.I believe, without allocationSize every db hit will trigger a Select to get the sequence.

Comment: I don't know the exact low-level mechanism used by every database. But with the ones I've used, an additional roundtrip to the database is needed to get the last auto-generated ID.

Answer (score 31):

The `IDENTITY` generator will always require a database hit for fetching the primary key value without waiting for the flush to synchronize the current entity state transitions with the database.

So the `IDENTITY` generator doesn't play well with Hibernate write-behind first level cache strategy, therefore JDBC batching is disabled for the [`IDENTITY`](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/) generator.

The sequence generator can benefit from database value preallocation and you can even employ a [`hi/lo`](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-hilo-algorithm/) optimization strategy.

In my opinion, the best generators are the `pooled` and [`pooled-lo`](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/) sequence generators. These generators combine the batch-friendly sequence generator with a client-side value generation optimization that's compatible with other DB clients that may insert rows without knowing anything about our generation strategy.

Anyway, you should never choose the [`TABLE`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) generator because it performs really bad.

Comment: What about TABLE generator with allocationSize config? Is it bad too?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. I'm going to use aurora and it doesn't support sequence. so I study table sequence... thanks for your articles.

Comment: When using MySQL DB, TABLE generator performs same as SEQUENCE generator. Since MySQL does not support sequences, it creates a sequence table to maintain a counter, which is similar to what table generator does. Therefore this statement is outdated I believe "Anyway, you should never choose the TABLE generator because it performs really bad"

Comment: @KnowIT I'm not sure how you came up with this conclusion. So, basically, you've found that MySQL falls back to the terrible TABLE generator, and for some reason, you assumed that's a good thing when it's not.  The TABLE generator requires a separate DB connection on which it uses exclusive locks just to give you the identifier. If you benchmark that against IDENTITY or SEQUENCE, you'll see that the TABLE generator performs way worse.

Comment: Just wanted to point out it should not be a blanket statement that "you should never choose the TABLE generator because it performs really bad". As, when using MySQL DB even if you plan to choose SEQUENCE generator, it also requires a separate DB connection on which it uses exclusive locks just to give you the identifier. 

Those developers who are using MySQL DB have no other option, but to use TABLE generator one way or the other, in certain cases.

Here's a link : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-sequence

Comment: @KnowIT [I wrote that part in the Hibernate manual](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/c2ece0108ed52d5e3a227ed0150cfb5cb1a76101), and it proves my point that the [TABLE generator is a terrible choice](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-mapping-identifiers). Just use the `IDENTITY` generator instead. The only minor drawback is that they will have to find a workaround for automatic batch inserts, either using jOOQ, JdbcTemplate, or using [this trick](https://vladmihalcea.com/batch-insert-mysql-hibernate/).

Comment: In a few cases, its not possible to use IDENTITY, like for example what if one has to generate an alphanumeric primary key? As to use true power of IDENTITY with MySQL in DDL we need to specify AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, and auto increment columns can't be VARCHAR in MySQL. Therefore to have an alphanumeric primary key we are left only with TABLE/SEQUENCE generator to use. Hence making a statement like "you should never choose the TABLE generator" should be avoided.

Comment: You can create an alphanumeric PK generator without the TABLE generator. You actually do it using an IDENTITY column on a table that creates the number part while the String part is assigned by a stored procedure. Or, you can use range locks and MAX(id). There are plenty of ways that are much better than TABLE, which you should not use. However, you don't have to take my advice. You can still use the TABLE generator even if I think it's a terrible idea. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm personally new to Hibernate, from what I can recall, using Identity basically means that Hibernate will check what is the next possible id value from your DB and keep a value for it.

For sequence, you basically tell Hibernate to generate the next value based on a particular sequence you provide it. So it has to actually calculate the next id by looking at the next possible id value. Hence, the extra query is fired.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will answer your question :

> Unlike identity column values, which are generated when rows are
>   inserted, an application can obtain the next sequence number before
>   inserting the row by calling the NEXT VALUE FOR function. The sequence
>   number is allocated when NEXT VALUE FOR is called even if the number
>   is never inserted into a table. The NEXT VALUE FOR function can be
>   used as the default value for a column in a table definition. Use
>   sp_sequence_get_range to get a range of multiple sequence numbers at
>   once.

you can find the detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx)

Identity doesnt need that extra select query because Identity is a table dependent and Sequence is independent from table, but because of this we can get sequence even before creating a row(when you do session.save(T entity), sequence is generated even before you commit the transaction).

sequence :
you create or update entities -> each time you save entity -> hibernate get next sequence value -> your program return the value after all process complete without exception or rollback -> you commit all transaction -> hibernate insert all complete entity

identity : when commit transaction, insert incomplete entity(must get it from identity column). so the **INSERT** command of sequence is definitely slower, but the advantages is if you cancel the insert the count doesn't increasing.

Comment: Thanks. In fact i too have gone through the links.if identity does not need that extra select query, then could you please clarify how sequence becomes faster than identity.

Comment: when in debug mode and use entity that have sequence for its id, i save(before commit) an entity and that entity already have id even before the row existed in the database.